# How to see actual numbers in a hist on R?

Tags: r

Just as an example I'm using iris data. I have a histogram, which is nice, but the distribution is weird, and I'd like to see what the bars represent:

Here's a histogram:

[image]

And I'd like to see the high/low that each bar represents. For instance, the first bar has a frequency of 34, but a width of something in the range of the lowest third of 0.0-0.5.

Obviously there won't be a width of 0.0, so what is the width range? How can I show it on the histogram?

Comment: I think you should clarify to indicates that by "high/low" you mean the range of width values each bucket represents. I think it's clear that the buckets cover a range of 0.2 by just inspecting the graph, and you would have been able to specify this when you made the histogram.

Comment: @SeanOwen The command I used was `hist(iris$pedal.width)` How do I control the bucket size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this may help you

```
hist(iris$Petal.Width,labels=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

To include the number of counts, you can just set `labels=TRUE.` The example below is just slightly adapted from one on the  `hist()` help page:

```
hist(iris$Petal.Width, labels = TRUE, ylim=c(0, 45))
```

### Solution 2

Adding percentages is a bit more involved as of now. You can easily do that by directly manipulate the object returned by a call to `hist()` as-

```
histPercent <- function(x, ...) {
   H <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
   H$density <- with(H, 100 * density* diff(breaks)[1])
   labs <- paste(round(H$density), "%", sep="")
   plot(H, freq = FALSE, labels = labs, ylim=c(0, 1.08*max(H$density)),...)
}

histPercent(iris$Petal.Width)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do this but:

```
library(dplyr)

data_frame(val=iris$Petal.Width,
           bin=cut(iris$Petal.Width, include.lowest=TRUE, # by default include.lowest defaults to TRUE in hist() 
                   breaks=hist(iris$Petal.Width, plot=FALSE)$breaks)) %>% 
  group_by(bin) %>% 
  do(as.data.frame(setNames(as.list(range(.$val)), c("low", "high"))))
## Source: local data frame [12 x 3]
## Groups: bin [12]
## 
##          bin   low  high
##       <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1    [0,0.2]   0.1   0.2
## 2  (0.2,0.4]   0.3   0.4
## 3  (0.4,0.6]   0.5   0.6
## 4    (0.8,1]   1.0   1.0
## 5    (1,1.2]   1.1   1.2
## 6  (1.2,1.4]   1.3   1.4
## 7  (1.4,1.6]   1.5   1.6
## 8  (1.6,1.8]   1.7   1.8
## 9    (1.8,2]   1.9   2.0
## 10   (2,2.2]   2.1   2.2
## 11 (2.2,2.4]   2.3   2.4
## 12 (2.4,2.6]   2.5   2.5
```